# Do I need to place the manifest.json file at the root of my webserver?

Tags: javascript, browser, progressive-web-apps, manifest, manifest.json

I read that on some sources and don't see any mention of that point on other, like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest).

I would like to have it in `/assets/manifest.json`. Even if that would work, I would still wonder if it is "working by design" or just "tolerated".

Answer (score 1):

You can have it anywhere you like and link to it like so:

```html
...<head>
<link rel="manifest" href="/assets/manifest.json" />
...</head>
```

As long as you modify the src of the assets in manifest.json this should be fine.